# datetime OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, eoserror

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def open_csv(path):
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(path)
        return df
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("ERR: FileNotFoundError", path)


data = open_csv("historical/BNBBTC")
for d in data["Open_time"]:
    print(d)
    print(type(d))
    print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

error: 
    `1514764800000
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    <class 'int'>
      File "D:/bot/add_data.py", line 16, in <module>
        print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

I can not understand what is the problem? If b = int ("1514764800000") then everything works!

Comment: You don't need your additional code, just modify `read_csv` to `df = pd.read_csv(path, parse_dates='Open_time')`

Answer (score 1):

kind of late, but the problem in your case is that timestamp is in milliSeconds, convert it like this:

```
        milliSeconds = timestamp % 1000
        timestamp = timestamp / 1000
        converted = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + f".{milliSeconds}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def epoch_to_date(epoch_time):
    time_stamp = epoch_time / 1000
    date_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time_stamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print(date_time)
    return date_time


epoch_time = epoch_to_date(epoch_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

`import time` and replace `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')` with `time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`